# Error loading jQuery on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are some post asking for this error. I have read about this error and I cannot solve.

I think that I load the JQuery library before the JavaScript is load. This is my head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin - MyMovie</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 

    </script>
</head>
```

And my scripts are loaded before I close the body:

```
 </div>
    <scrip src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></scrip>
    <script src="js/scripts.js" ></script>
</body>
```

When the browser parses the script.js in the line 18 I get the error:

> Reference Error $ is not defined.

The 18 line is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hola"); 
    $('#main-div').load('prueba.html');    
});
```

I don't understand this error because first I loaded the CDN and after that I loaded my Javascript Code.

Someone can help me?

Comment: you need to load jquery before bootstrap, as the bootstrap requires jquery

Comment: I don't know if its a typo... but you spelled <scrip> instead of <script>

Comment: I cant believe,  I was locking for a new order, change the order a lot times and change URL CDN... thanks =( the error was the "scrip"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the error is coming from script.js, it should be coming from the bootstrap.js file as bootstrap js file depends on jQuery. So move the bootstrap script to bottom of the page after `jQuery`

Also the script tag of jQuery has a spelling mistake

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" ></script>
```

Comment: its probably coming from scripts.js since he typed  `scrip` instead of `script`

Comment: @FelipeSkinner yes... but also bootstrap script location

Answer (score 1):

You should move this:

```
<scrip src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></scrip>
```

to your head section, before the bootsrap js. Take care that you have a typo in this tag: scrip instead of script.
So this should become:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
Try Follwing CDN
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    </head>

or

    <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

and also correct your `<script>` tag typo

Answer (score -1):

try like bellow code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert('hello'); /* `enter code here` */
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: How could that possibly help. You're passing `jQuery` as an argument to what exactly?